# How do you change the style of pybtex references in sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, pybtex

I'm trying to use the [sphinxcontrib.bibtex](https://sphinxcontrib-bibtex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to include citations/references in some documentation. It says that you can [set the style](https://sphinxcontrib-bibtex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#directive-bibliography) with:

```
.. bibliography: refs.bib
   :style: plain
```

And it comes with the following styles: `alpha`, `plain` which create reference labels that look like this:

- `alpha`: `[ZieglerBenderSchreiber+14]` or `[TMT14]` or `[PCY+16a]`
- `plain`: `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]`

I find that `alpha` is inconsistent but I think that the just-numbers of `plain` lack context. To customize formatting it provides this example:

```
from pybtex.style.formatting.unsrt import Style as UnsrtStyle
from pybtex.style.template import toplevel # ... and anything else needed
from pybtex.plugin import register_plugin

class MyStyle(UnsrtStyle):

    def format_XXX(self, e):
        template = toplevel [
            # etc.
        ]
        return template.format_data(e)

register_plugin('pybtex.style.formatting', 'mystyle', MyStyle)
```

which `sphinx` fails out on with:

```
sphinx-build -M html . out
Running Sphinx v1.8.3

Configuration error:
There is a syntax error in your configuration file: bad input (conf.py, line 92)
Did you change the syntax from 2.x to 3.x?
```

It seems to use [pybtex](https://docs.pybtex.org/api/styles.html#pybtex.style.formatting.BaseStyle) under the hood so following an example from that documentation:

```
from pybtex.style.formatting import BaseStyle
from pybtex.richtext import Text, Tag

class MyStyle(BaseStyle):
    def format_article(self, entry):
        return Text('Article ', Tag('em', entry.fields['title']))

from pybtex.plugin import register_plugin
register_plugin('pybtex.style.formatting', 'mystyle', MyStyle)
```

and sphinx fails out with:

```
Exception occurred:
  File "/home/josh/codes/docs/conf.py", line 88, in format_article
    return Text('Article ', Tag('em', entry.fields['title']))
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'fields'
The full traceback has been saved in /tmp/sphinx-err-dftwlzvr.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers.
```

... and I think that just customizes the bibliography entry text and not the label text anyway. How do I customize the label text? I would prefer one of the following:

1. just bracket numerals (`[1]`) like `plain`, but with labels in superscript
2. something like `[ref.12]` similar to `eq.12` or `fig.12`
3. something like `alpha` but with a consistent number of characters

Answer (score 2):

I hate to answer my own question, but here's what I figured out. I added the following to my `conf.py` and it uses the bibtex key for the label text:

```
from pybtex.style.formatting.unsrt import Style as UnsrtStyle
from pybtex.style.labels.alpha import LabelStyle as AlphaLabelStyle

class KeyLabelStyle(AlphaLabelStyle):
  def format_label(self, entry):
    label = entry.key
    return label

class CustomStyle(UnsrtStyle):
  default_sorting_style = 'author_year_title'

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomStyle, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.label_style = KeyLabelStyle()
    self.format_labels = self.label_style.format_labels

from pybtex.plugin import register_plugin
register_plugin('pybtex.style.formatting', 'custom', CustomStyle)
```

To activate in RST:

```
.. bibliography:: refs.bib
   :style: custom
```

This isn't a complete answer however as it doesn't really generate custom labels... but overrides some internals of an existing style. So kind of a hacky almost-answer... I hope it helps someone else.